# Improving time complexity/efficiency for this Python for loop code

Tags: python

Can you help me optimize the code. This is in Python:

```
for fruit in fruit_list:
    fruit_id = uuid.uuid4()
    fruit_nos.append(TotalFruits(fruit_id, fruit))
```

(1) So there's a fruit list that contains a list of fruits

(2) For each fruit we generate a fruit_id using uuid

(3) We pass the fruit_id and the fruit to a class Total Fruits that returns the total number of fruits of that variety

(4) We append that to a fruit_nos list

I was trying to do list comprehensions but  `fruit_id = uuid.uuid4()` is becoming a problem. So, I would do:

```
fruit_nos = [TotalFruits(fruit_id, fruit) for fruit in fruit_list]
```

But of course, I'll miss the uuid part. Is there an efficient way to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the `uuid` within the comprehension:

```
fruit_nos = [TotalFruits(uuid.uuid4(), fruit) for fruit in fruit_list]
```

Note: `uuid.uuid4()` returns a UUID object. If you need a string - try using the `hex` attribute of that object: `uuid.uuid4().hex`

Answer (score 0):

You can include `fruit_id = uuid.uuid4()` inside the Class then you can use the list comp